# Background image appears zoomed in on mobile screens

Tags: css, background-image, viewport

I'm building a project for school, and I'm having issues with the background image. I've used this code snippet to do it (https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/), and it works fine on desktop and on Chrome Dev Tools (for mobile devices, that is). It doesn't work properly when I open my website on Chrome or Safari on my phone. Screenshots as follows:

[Chrome on Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXcXM.png)

[Chrome on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeGzN.png)

Here's my code on CSS:

```
.container-hero {
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
background: url("../images/hero-image.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-ms-flex-align: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-ms-flex-pack: center;
justify-content: center;
```

}

```
<div class="container-fluid container-hero">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="hero-j jumbotron text-center text-uppercase text-white">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h1 class="display-4 section-header">Be a hero.</h1>
                        <hr class="block-divider--white">
                        <p class="hero-j text"> At Doug's, we <strong>Evolve</strong> together.</p>
                        <a href="#signup" class="btn btn-lg button-signup">
                        Sign me up!
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you post your HTML code as well? Also, what exactly do you want your background to look like on mobile?

Comment: Hi, what phone and OS and browser versions are you using?

Comment: Hey guys, I've added the html div concerning that class on CSS - hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

IOS Safari, and therefore IOS Chrome, does not support fixed on background. See https://caniuse.com/?search=fixed

I tried your CSS with my own image and it was fuzzy. Taking the fixed out of this statement made it clear.

```
background: url("https://ahweb.org.uk/gear.jpg") no-repeat center center;
```

Without knowing the exact layout of your code it is difficult to know whether this will be enough or whether you will have to take the image out to be the background of another container so it remains in view at all times if that is what is required.

Comment: Brilliant, that works! Thank you very much, I've been trying to sort this out for ages!